# phantomJS rails controller localhost not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, localhost, screenshot, screen-capture

I'm having a strange problem with PhantomJS and capturing a screenshot when the code is called from inside my rails controller AND it's opening a page from the same application - ie. localhost:3000/my/page. Outside of the rails controller (rails console or directly from terminal, it works fine). External URLs such as google.com, amazon.com work fine too.

**What I can see:**

phantomjs stops after `page.onLoadStarted` and never goes beyond that.

**What I've tried:**

Different servers:
Webrick, Puma and Unicorn and all have the same problem.

Different IPs:
I've changed the url inside the script.js file to load localhost, an internal IP and an external IP that connects to rails app. They all fail.

script.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost:3000/my/page');
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    page.render('image.png');
    phantom.exit();
}
```

I don't think the problem is with script.js because if I run `phantomjs script.js` in terminal, it works.

Is it not possible to get a screenshot from the same server that is initializing phantomjs, even if it's a different page/controller?

Comment: Perhaps it's a same origin issue?